# Tracing python code with variables in the loop using debugger

Tags: python, loops, variables

I'm trying to understand the change of variable in python code using python debugger and this is the result I got for 3 variable. Am I understanding this correctly?

```
payroll = [2000, 3000, 1500]
authorised = 0
overpaid = []

for place in range(len(payroll)):
    if payroll[place] > 2000:
        overpaid.append(place)
    else:
        authorised = authorised + payroll[place]
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have any questions regarding your understanding as in you expect something else but not getting that?

Comment: You are correct. But right columns show results before the left statement. If you write the result after operation, I guess it will be more understandable.

Comment: When I run the exact same code I get that authorized = 3500 and overpaid = [1]

Comment: And what is your understanding?

Comment: I was thinking that third iteration of the loop "authorised" should change to 3500 but debugger gives me 2000, so I'm kind of lost